# Error while consuming a REST API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to consume `REST` API which takes `JSON` payload and returns plain/text in the response. But I am getting following error during runtime.

**SpotifyIntegrationApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpotifyIntegrationApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpotifyIntegrationApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpotifyIntegrationApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        NewOrder newOrder = new NewOrder();
        return args -> {
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:9999/order-sold", newOrder, String.class);
            LOGGER.info("responseEntity: " + responseEntity);
        };
    }

}
```

**NewOrder.java**

```
public class NewOrder {
    String orderId;
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.synapse.integration'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.synapse.integration.spotify.SpotifyIntegrationApplication.main(SpotifyIntegrationApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.synapse.integration.spotify.model.NewOrder]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:907) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:658) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:415) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.synapse.integration.spotify.SpotifyIntegrationApplication.lambda$run$0(SpotifyIntegrationApplication.java:32) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You probably need to use an [HttpEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html) instead of just your pojo instance: `restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:9999/order-sold", new HttpEntity<>(new NewOrder()), String.class);` ([more examples](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template))

Comment: try adding content type header

Comment: @Morfic - Tried putting in the new HttpEntity but no luck. Still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 I have used restTemplate.exchange but you can modify to use postForEntity 
 or postForObject. Hope this helps.

 private HttpHeaders createHttpHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return headers;
    }

@RequestMapping("/testClient")
public String testClient() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = createHttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters",
            headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    if (response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
        System.out.println("getbody -" + response.getBody());
    }
    return "Test Client";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the request made accepts only json, then provide headers specifying the content-type and convert the object to json( use Gson to convert object to json) and make a post request by setting all these to a **HttpEntity**

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("content-type", "application/json");
headers.add("accept", "application/json");

String requestBody = gson.toJson(requestObject);

HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity(requestBody,headers);
```

and make the rest call as

```
restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl,HttpMethod.POST,httpEntity,MyResponse.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution from above responses plus from some additional googling.

**SpotifyIntegrationApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpotifyIntegrationApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpotifyIntegrationApplication.class);
    public static final String ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:9999/order-sold";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpotifyIntegrationApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        return args -> {
            NewOrder newOrder = new NewOrder();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            HttpEntity<NewOrder> entity = new HttpEntity<>(newOrder, headers);
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(ENDPOINT, POST, entity, String.class);
            LOGGER.info("responseEntity: " + responseEntity);
        };
    }

}
```

**NewOrder.java**

```
@Data
public class NewOrder {

    private String orderId;

}
```

Although this was not part of the original question but also removed Tomcat library dependency since I am just consuming the API and not building one.

**build.gradle**

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the answers are all a bit confusing, when looking at Spring's documentation at:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

It seems you should be able to successfully consume a response, map to a JSON object via annotated object.

However, even in doing this:

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
    return args -> {
        Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://localhost:8978/greeting", Quote.class);
        System.out.println(quote.toString());
        log.info(quote.toString());      
    };
```

I'm still getting the above Failed to execute CommandLineRunner error, going to have to investigate if its worth actually mapping to the HttpResponseObject. Hopefully there are some thoughts on my comment here.